How to find all fields when assigning value to a struct
If you are writing go in goland and assigning a value to a struct, you can type ff hot key to find all fields in a second.

Then it will be like:

It's very convenient when you are dealing with a huge struct.
But how can I do it in vscode? Is there any hot key can do similar action? Does somebody know?

if you don't have an extension that does implement this Code Action (Ctrl+.), you can write one yourself, or create an issue at the go language server extension

You can try:

installing the Go extension
placing your cursor on the empty instance
pressing Ctrl + Shift + R (or the MacOS equivalent) for "Rewrite" / "Refactor"
choosing "Fill StructName"


